# How to successfully set a ref for a <TreeNode>

Tags: reactjs, antd

I cannot add a ref to TreeNode elements as it is a functional component.

I cannot wrap each TreeNode as Tree only accepts TreeNode as children, so React.forwardRef cannot be used.

How to set a ref for a TreeNode then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign a reference to a `Tree.TreeNode` directly.

But, you can access its reference through `Tree`:

```
nodeRef.current.tree.domTreeNodes
```

Example:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Tree } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

const { TreeNode } = Tree;

const App = () => {
  const nodeRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(nodeRef.current.tree.domTreeNodes);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Tree
      ref={nodeRef}
      checkable
      defaultExpandedKeys={['0-0-0', '0-0-1']}
      defaultSelectedKeys={['0-0-0', '0-0-1']}
      defaultCheckedKeys={['0-0-0', '0-0-1']}
    >
      <TreeNode title="parent 1" key="0-0">
        <TreeNode title="parent 1-0" key="0-0-0" disabled>
          <TreeNode title="leaf" key="0-0-0-0" disableCheckbox />
          <TreeNode title="leaf" key="0-0-0-1" />
        </TreeNode>
        <TreeNode title="parent 1-1" key="0-0-1">
          <TreeNode
            title={<span style={{ color: '#1890ff' }}>sss</span>}
            key="0-0-1-0"
          />
        </TreeNode>
      </TreeNode>
    </Tree>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit Q-59175476-TreeNodeRef]